# React axios проблема с обработкой ответа с сервера

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, axios

Помогите найти ошибку при следующем действии:
есть **agent.tsx**

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios"

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

const requests = {
    get: (url: string) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
    post: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: (url: string, body: {}) => axios.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
    delete: (url: string) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody),
};

const Catalog = {
    list: () => requests.get('Products'),
    details: (id: number) => requests.get(`Products/${id}`),
};

const agent = {
    Catalog
};

export default agent;
```

и вот место в другом файле, где я дергаю его:

```
export default function ProductDetails(){
const {id} = useParams<{id: string}>();
const [product, setProduct] = useState<Product | null>(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    agent.Catalog.details(parseInt(id as string))
        .then(response => setProduct(response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, [id])
```

вариант выше не работает, однако такой вариант вполне себе делают все нормально:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://localhost:5001/api/Products/${id}`)
        .then(response => setProduct(response.data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}, [id])
```

Если использовать нерабочий вариант и вывести в консоль `response`, то получится нужный json, а если вывести `response.data` - пишет **undefined**. Подскажите что не так.

Answer (score 0):

Да, бывает и такое: `.then(response => setProduct(response.data))` на `.then(response => setProduct(response))` и все будет в порядке.